# Teamcity Environment Variable Substitution

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I am trying to achieve something simple. The below bash script runs in Teamcity

```
#!/bin/bash
awsEnv=%env.environment%
s3Bucket="%%env.${'$'}{awsEnv^^}_S3_BUCKET%%"
aws s3 cp test.json s3://${'$'}s3Bucket/artifacts/output.json
```

I have an environment variable `%env.environment%` whose value can be `DEV` or `stg` or `PROD`. If `DEV` is the value provided at input, the bash script tries to construct another
environment variable dynamically in this case `%env.DEV_S3_BUCKET%` as shown in line 2. This in turn is used in `aws s3 cp` step.

However when this is run in Teamcity, this is the error it throws

```
upload failed: test.json to s3://%env.DEV_S3_BUCKET%/artifacts/output.json Parameter validation failed:
04:54:07
  Invalid bucket name "%env.DEV_S3_BUCKET%" : Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"
```

I would have expected it to substitute the value for `%env.DEV_S3_BUCKET%` but it did not.

What am I missing here? Is this possible to do this within a single step in Teamcity?

P.S. The environment variable `%env.DEV_S3_BUCKET%` is already defined in Teamcity.

Answer (score 0):

To edit environment variable between two build steps you probably need to use TeamCity service messages to update the value on the TeamCity server.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html#Adding+or+Changing+a+Build+Parameter

You'll need to

`echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.environment' value='new_value']"`

TeamCity will pick it up and it will be accessible in the next steps.

Comment: The question was about substituting for env variables within a step. Even though I construct the env variable, its not substituting the value for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a way to do this using `$` and `!` instead of `%env.<param>%`

```
#!/bin/bash
awsEnv=%env.environment%
s3Bucket="${'$'}{awsEnv^^}_S3_BUCKET"
aws s3 cp test.json s3://${'$'}{!s3Bucket}/artifacts/output.json
```

Comment: Is ${'$'}{!s3Bucket} getting a value from teamcity itself? Or does it just point do DEV_S3_BUCKET?